# Reducir Selección en Expresiones Regulares

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un conjunto de cadenas en formato

```
{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_1}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_1} {NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2} {NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2}
```

La idea es con el uso de una expresión regular poder capturar cada `{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_i}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_i}`
Por separado
He probado varias expresiones,

```
[{](.*)[}]=[{](.*)[}]
[{](.*)[}]=[{](.*)[}][ ]
[{]<.*>[}]=[{]<.*>[}]
[{]<.*>[}]=[{]<.*>[}][ ]
```

pero casi siempre lo que capturan es la cadena completa
Supongo que es por el formato repetitivo dentro de la cadena donde talvez interpreta que debe seleccionar la mayor coincidencia y toma ha `{…}={... las sub selecciones …}` de toda la cadena
Parte del problema es que no debo usar un Split (método en algún idioma) para separar los pares basado en los `“{ }”` porque el `CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_i` puede internamente también contener estos caracteres
Lo que necesito es una forma de poder decirle que a la primera menor coincidencia la tome y así sucesivamente, no sé si me explico correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar una expresión regular también para dividir (`split`) la cadena que, tal vez, sea la forma más simple:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile("(?<=})\s+(?={)")

pat.split("{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_1}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_1} {NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2} {NOMBRE_INFORMACION_3}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_3}")
# --->
['{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_1}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_1}',
'{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2}',
'{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_3}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_3}']
```

En la expresión regular, buscamos grupos de varios espacios en blanco `'\s+'` que estén precedidos por una llave de cierre `'}'` (`(?<=})`) y seguido de una llave de apertura `'{'` (`(?={)`), y partimos la cadena por esos espacios en blanco.

Pero comentas que los contenidos pueden complicarse introduciendo *"anidamiento"* de corchetes. Las expresiones regulares se pueden complicar todo lo que quieras, aunque cada vez será más difícil seguir lo que están haciendo.

Lo que queremos es detectar un bloque que empiece por `{`, termine en `}` seguido de `=` y de otro bloque que empiece por `{` y termine en `}` y luego espacios.

En expresión regular: `'{[^=]*}={\S*}'`

El primer bloque se extenderá hasta encontrar el `=` y el segundo bloque se extenderá hasta encontrar un espacio o finalizar la cadena.

```py
import re

pat = re.compile('{[^=]*}={\S*}')

pat.findall("{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_1}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_1} {NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_{INFORMACION}_2} {{{NOMB}RE}_INFO{RMACION_3}}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_3}")
# --->
['{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_1}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_1}',
'{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_{INFORMACION}_2}',
'{{{NOMB}RE}_INFO{RMACION_3}}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_3}']
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario usar expresiones regulares.

Tu entrada es de la forma

```
{abc}={d e f} {123}={1+2=3}
```

y quieres separarla en una lista de forma

```
["{abc}={d e f}", "{123}={1+2=3}"]
```

Este código toma una cadena con asignaciones y produce una lista de cadenas, cada una con una sala asignación.

```
texto = "{abc}={d e f} {123}={1+2=3}"

pos = 0
lista = []
while pos < len(texto):
    pos = texto.find("{", pos)
    pos_end = texto.find("}", pos + 1)
    pos_end = texto.find("}", pos_end + 1) + 1
    lista.append(texto[pos:pos_end])
    pos = pos_end
print(lista)
```

El `while` recorre la cadena caracter por caracter. Suponiendo que la cadena está bien formada, busca el primer "{". De ahi busca el primer "}", justo antes del "=", y luego el segundo "}", que termina la asignación.

Teniendo las posiciones de comienzo y fin dentro de la cadena, podemos extraer esa asignación y agregarla a la lista en formación.

La variable `pos` avanza monotonamente a través de la cadena, siempre señalando el comienzo de la asignación que estamos examinando.

#### Usando expresiones regulares

El patrón es `({.*?}={.*?})\s*`. El truco está en usar el patrón *non-greedy* `.*?`, de manera que el match realizado por `.*` sea lo más corto posible

```
import re
texto ="{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_1}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_1} {NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2} {NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2}"
patron = re.compile(r'({.*?}={.*?})\s*')

m = patron.findall(texto)
print(m)
```

produce:

```
['{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_1}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_1}', '{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2}', '{NOMBRE_INFORMACION_2}={CONTENIDO_INFORMACION_2}']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: gracias, y si funciona el código que propones, pero conoces de alguna forma mediante alguna expresión regular?

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo de agregarme lo de las expresiones regulares, realmente ayuda